# Impact of Sampling from portion of Population

Tags: sampling, mean, binomial-distribution

So here is a scenario that I am looking at.

There is a population that has a binary variable of interest. This population was collected over a year. The population was sampled and mean of that variable was calculated.

However, later the population was pulled again and it had changed very slightly.  There were now 0.66% more items in this population.  The reason for this is that it is possible for a new item to be added and backdated.  Practically, this means that all the new items were at the very end of that year window.

This means that the sample is not representative of the population ever so slightly.  What is the impact of the sample statistic?  Would the confidence interval just increase?  Does the whole thing need to be junked?

Because it could help, I will spell out the values.
Initially, there were 9,964 items.  310 of those were sampled.  136 of the sample had the value of False for the variable of interest.  The 95% confidence interval is [0.383, 0.496]

Later, the population was revised to 10,030, all of the 66 new items are in the last month of the population.  Of any sample of 66 within the initial population, 95% of the time between 0-4 were sampled.  So with that thought, perhaps the actual value of the sample with False is really between 132 - 140.
Would it be correct to take the lower bound of the confidence interval of 132 and the upper bound for 140?  This would mean the 95% confidence interval is really [0.370, 0.509].

My intuition is that this is junk, but I guess how junk is it?  Its not like this is for a scientific journal, but at the same time decisions are being made off of this.  Thanks.

Comment: How was the initial sample chosen?  Is it random?

Comment: Yes, there are no issues with the sampling method.  Its just that it turns out the entire population was not eligible.